# How do I disable Ubisoft Connect popups?

Tags: nintendo-switch, ubisoft-connect, immortals-fenyx-rising

I'm playing Immortals: Fenyx Rising on Nintendo Switch and have changed the HUD settings to disable a lot of the pop-ups that cover the screen. I can't figure out how to disable the pop-ups from Ubisoft Connect whenever I complete an achievement(?), and they're big and cover a lot of the screen. I got through all of the regular gameplay and didn't have an issue with these pop-ups until I downloaded some of the DLCs (currently playing A New God). Either I found a way to disable them in the past, or playing the DLC unlocked new achievements.

I've looked in the game HUD settings and the Ubisoft Connect settings and haven't found anything related to these pop-ups. Is there a way to disable them?

Answer (score 1):

From your [Ubisoft Connect dashboard](https://ubisoftconnect.com/it-IT/dashboard/) you can download and install *Ubisoft Connect* on your PC.

From there:

- Open the three-line menu in the top left corner of your screen.
- Select Settings.
- Under the General tab, uncheck "Enable in-game overlay for supported games".

[image]

I didn't manage to find that setting on the site. I hope this works for every connected platform.

<sub>Source, [Ubisoft support](https://www.ubisoft.com/en-gb/help/connectivity-and-performance/article/disabling-the-ubisoft-connect-overlay/000064954).</sub>

Comment: I followed these instructions and also unchecked a similar setting in the Notifications section. Played for an hour last night and didn't see any pop-ups, so hopefully that solved it!

Comment: @DavidK hope so!

Comment: Unfortunately I have to unaccept this answer. I've gotten a few more pop-ups showing up even with this setting disabled. I think the only solution is to just keep playing until most of the achievements are unlocked and so fewer appear on the screen :-/

Comment: @DavidK uhm sorry about that... the funny thing is that this is the solution provided from Ubisoft support, so.. well done. This probably works only for PC version then.